# Import/export entities to/from XML

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework

[image]**Environment and setup:**
Using Entity Framework 6.1.3 (code-first) and .NET 4.5.2.

**Question:**
I have a database layout with common table associations, according to attached diagram below. (Note! Not all entities are shown). For now I just seed the database from my unittests, but in the future create/remove/update/delete from a custom application. However, for now I would rather find a way to let users create new records from XML. Hence, I need to find out if I can import XML and seed the database from it. Since the entities have mostly one-to-many and many-to-many associations I imagine that the serialization is not without problems. How would you solve it?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by import/export entities and xml? and why need that

Comment: Lei Yang: Initially to save time. I have no time to implement a custom application to let users define the testcases. But I am not sure if that is the best way to do it, maybe there is better ideas to deal with it?

Comment: testcase? what do you want to test?

Comment: did you ever solve it?